# Sencha Touch 2.3 - how to scroll vertically with scrolling operating on more than one container

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am making the screen as in picture and as in code below. Note that the vertical scrolling is only functional on the listview. Is there a way in which I can make the vertical scrolling operate across the entire window - so that the picture and the profile text on top disappear and not stay in the viewport always when scrolling?

[image]

```
Ext.define('Volt.view.FeedView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'Ext.Button',
        'Ext.Toolbar',
        'Volt.view.FeedListView'
    ],

    xtype: 'feedViewCard',

    config: {
        iconCls: 'home',
        title: 'FeedView',

        layout: {
            type: 'vbox'
        },

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                title: 'Home',
                docked: 'top',
                items: [

                    //2 buttons here
                ]
            },
            {
                // profile summary at top
                xtype: 'container',
                flex: 1,
                layout: 'hbox',
                items:[
                    {
                        //picture of user
                        xtype: 'image',
                        src: 'http://www.sencha.com/assets/images/sencha-avatar-64x64.png',
                        flex: 1
                    },
                    {
                        //text and EM count
                        xtype: 'container',
                        flex:2,
                        html:'profile text and earthmiles count'
                    }
                ]


            },
            {
                xtype: 'list',
                //more code here

            }
        ]
    },





});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the whole panel scrollable, like this:-

```
Ext.define('Volt.view.FeedView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'Ext.Button',
        'Ext.Toolbar',
        'Volt.view.FeedListView'
    ],

    xtype: 'feedViewCard',

    config: {
        iconCls: 'home',
        title: 'FeedView',
        scrollable: 'vertical', // or true
   ...
```